# Completeness and model completeness of the first order theory of Valuation rings

Tags: logic, commutative-algebra, first-order-logic, model-theory, valuation-theory

Let $L$ be a the first order language of rings with unity. Let $T$ be the first order theory of Valuation rings, which along with the first order axioms for  integral domain, contains the following axiom : $\forall a \forall b ((\exists r (ra=b)) \lor (\exists s (sb=a)))$.

Is this first order theory of Valuation rings complete ? model complete ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that models for this theory are both fields and non-fields.

In particular, the sentence $(\forall x)[(x \neq 0) \rightarrow (\exists y)(xy=1)]$ is not decidable from the axioms.

Similarly, embedding of a non-field valuation ring $D$ to its field of fraction $F$ will not be an elementary embedding. The formula $(\exists y)(xy=1)$ will be true about a non-zero element $a \in \mathfrak{m}$ in the maximal ideal of $D$ when taken in $F$, but not true in $D$.

Or do you consider something like $(\exists x)[(x\neq 0)\wedge(\forall y)(xy\neq 1)]$ an axiom of integral domains (excluding fields)?

Comment: Thanks for your answer ... if I indeed excluded the fields by adding the axiom you mention , what would the completeness of the theory be like then ?

Comment: Then the theory would still not be complete: Another statement you can talk about is characteristic. That is, the sentence $1+1=0$ can be true (in, say, $\mathbb{F}_2[[x]]$) and also false (in $\mathbb{Q}[[x]]$).

Comment: what about model completeness ?

Comment: Actually it is still far from being model complete as well as complete: Consider e.g. $\mathbb{Q}[[x]]\subseteq \mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}][[x]]$. This is not an elementary embedding, because the sentence $(\exists y)(y \cdot y=1+1)$ is satisfied in $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}][[x]]$, but not in $\mathbb{Q}[[x]]$. And you can do this with every algebraic relation over a prime field, essentially.